# what's best way to add multiple image to progrram(qt)

Tags: qt, resources

I want use some image in my application(`number : over than 600 image, size over than 40mb`).

I know it's not good if I add them to qt resource file and build them. Where should I add them and use ? (*for example in a dll file or ....*)
and I want the user have no ability for access them easily

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to put 40 MB of images in your executable.

If you want to keep it as one single big file, you could cram all images together in a single binary file, and make a map of where each file begins and ends, then based on that map read images from segments in that file. This will make it hard for an average user to access the images directly, and almost impossible to modify, as any change to the size of any of the images will break the whole thing.